# How to use trained svm model to predict whether image contains a car object or not

Tags: matlab, svm

I want to use the svm classifying whether an image contains car or not.

I trained svm classifier using HOG. Then I try to use the classifier, so I looked up certain Mathworks tutorial.
I could not fined any useful tutorial for using svm classifier.

I use the data set from http://cogcomp.org/Data/Car/

This is my code for svm classifier.

```matlab
imgPos = imread(strrep(file, '*', int2str(0)));

[hog_4x4, vis4x4] = extractHOGFeatures(imgPos,'CellSize',[4 4]);
cellSize = [4 4];
hogFeatureSize = length(hog_4x4);

temp(1:500) = 1;
temp(501:1000) = 0;

trainingLabels = categorical(temp);
trainingFeatures = zeros(fileNum*2, hogFeatureSize, 'single');

for n = 1:500
    posfile = strrep(posFile, "*", int2str(n-1));
    imgPos = imread(posfile); 
    trainingFeatures(n, :) = extractHOGFeatures(imgPos, 'CellSize', cellSize);

    negfile = strrep(negFile, "*", int2str(n-1));
    imgNeg = imread(negfile);
    trainingFeatures(n+500, :) = extractHOGFeatures(imgNeg, 'CellSize', cellSize);
end

classifier = fitcecoc(trainingFeatures, trainingLabels);
```

I want use the classifier to detect car objects.
If it's possible I want to surround each detected car object with frame.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for the `predict` method. Get your test data features and run the following:

```
predictions = predict(classifier, testFeatures);
```